# how to iterate through a list of tuples with lists and group elements sequentially?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this list

```
lis = [(0, [75, 1, 30]), (1, [41, 49, 55]), (2, [28, 53, 45])]
```

and I'm trying to group these values sequentially together in tuples. What would be a way to do this?

Expected output is

```
[(0,75), (75, 1), (1, 30), (1, 41), (41,49), (49,55), (2,28), (28, 53), (53, 45)] 


found = []
for tup in edge_list:
    found.append((tup[0], tup[1][0]))
    found.append((tup[1][0], tup[1][1]))
    found.append((tup[1][1], tup[1][2]))
print(found)
```

is there a better/easier approach to iterate over this no matter what the size of the second tuple looks like

```
[(0, [82, 70, 79, 77, 42]), (1, [40, 61, 58, 66, 69]), (2, [80, 30, 12, 77, 9])]
```

Comment: Can you go from `(0, [75, 1, 30])` to `[(0,75), (75, 1), (1, 30)]`?

Comment: can you may be just give a shortest possible example so it's easier to understand?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati The example is already just a single line. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: I edited my question, I want to have an iterator which will sequentially group the elements together no matter the size of the second tuple if it was 3, 5, or 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful trick is to flatten out the elements of `lis` via the `*` operator:

```
>>> lis = [(0, [75, 1, 30]), (1, [41, 49, 55]), (2, [28, 53, 45])]
>>> [(a, *b) for a, b in lis]
[(0, 75, 1, 30), (1, 41, 49, 55), (2, 28, 53, 45)]
```

Given any sequence, you can produce the kind of pairing you're looking for by `zip`ping it with an offset version of itself:

```
>>> list(zip(s, s[1:]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Combining those two techniques (i.e. taking the sequences within `lis` and then converting them into pairs), you can do:

```
>>> [list(zip((a, *b), b)) for a, b in lis]
[[(0, 75), (75, 1), (1, 30)], [(1, 41), (41, 49), (49, 55)], [(2, 28), (28, 53), (53, 45)]]
```

and to get them all into a single list of pairs, we can do a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [z for a, b in lis for z in zip((a, *b), b)]
[(0, 75), (75, 1), (1, 30), (1, 41), (41, 49), (49, 55), (2, 28), (28, 53), (53, 45)]
```

Answer (score 1):

using list unpacking and zip method

```
In [49]: lis = [(0, [75, 1, 30]), (1, [41, 49, 55]), (2, [28, 53, 45])]

In [50]: result = []
    ...: for a, b in lis:
    ...:     res = [a, *b]
    ...:     for i, j in zip(res, res[1:]):
    ...:         result.append((i,j))
    ...: 

In [51]: result
Out[51]: 
[(0, 75),
 (75, 1),
 (1, 30),
 (1, 41),
 (41, 49),
 (49, 55),
 (2, 28),
 (28, 53),
 (53, 45)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Having fun with itertools...

```py
from itertools import pairwise, chain

lis = [(0, [75, 1, 30]), (1, [41, 49, 55]), (2, [28, 53, 45])]

found = [*chain(*(pairwise(a) for *a, a[1:] in lis))]

print(found)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9LCsIwEIb3OcW_TEqEPvEBniR0EbSlA20S0hTxLG660Y0n8jam1W6GmQ_-xzxe7h46a-b5OYV2d_i8W28HUGh8sLYfQYOzPsBp8jcaG4lLp8kw1tOIMxRPJdS-ksgkirQWEjxuqoyjPEpU1YryiPJDPIuII6oZa-1krotDshryhG8RXAu01iPRElplpxpkEOPEInOeTOCrWLBf5X_z7YMv)

Comment: i'm getting something like this [(0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (0,1), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)] how to get rid of repeated (2, 2) and only keep (0,1) out of (1,0),(0,1)?

Comment: @learner_from_scratch There are multiple ways to do that, but it would need more specification and it would be another question.

Comment: can you pls take a look in case we're talking about edges to lose self loops and parallel edges 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75492991/get-rid-of-repeated-self-values-and-keep-only-one-out-of-2-0-0-2