# get rid of repeated self values and keep only one out of (2,0) (0,2)?

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

according to @KellyBundy answer, I'd like to get rid of repeated self-values `(2, 2), (0, 0)`
and keep only either `(2, 1) or (1, 2), keep only either (1, 0) or (0, 1)`  and get rid of `repeated (0, 2)`

```
 [(0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (0,2),  (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)]
```

out of this
from itertools import pairwise, chain

```
lis = [(0, [75, 1, 30]), (1, [41, 49, 55]), (2, [28, 53, 45])]

found = [*chain(*(pairwise(a) for *a, a[1:] in lis))]

print(found)
```

Comment: Are inner or outer order important? If you have `[(1,2), (2,1), (4,3)]`, would result `[(3,4), (1,2)]` be ok? (Note the (4,3) became (3,4) and moved to the front.)

Comment: And you might want to make this about getting your final result from `lis` instead of from `found`. It's probably better to adjust Samwise's answer of your old question and build your final result directly instead of via that `found` list.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. Questions here should be able to stand on their own.

Comment: thank you, my question has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist =  [(0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (0,2),  (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)]
seen = set()
final = [(i,j) for i,j in mylist if i!=j and (i+j, abs(i-j)) not in seen and not seen.add((i+j, abs(i-j)))]
```

we filter on ((i+j), abs(i-j))

if you really need a one liner, we can use a lambda function

```
list(filter(lambda e, seen=set(): e[0]!=e[1] and (e[0]+e[1], abs(e[0]-e[1])) not in seen and not seen.add((e[0]+e[1], abs(e[0]-e[1]))), mylist))
```

i+j and abs(i-j) here are the sum and absolute difference. It makes the logic simpler since (x,y) and (y,x) have the same absolute difference and the same sum.
(i+j, abs(i+j)) is a tuple containing both the sum and absolute difference

seen here is a python [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which can be used to efficiently check if something already exists within it.

Comment: can you pls explain your idea more in here (i+j, abs(i-j)) and seen.add((i+j, abs(i-j)))?

Comment: @learner_from_scratch added explanation